# I need to COUNT the number of leads a user has at any one time

Tags: mysql

I am trying to Count the leads that a user will have at any specific time but i am getting an error MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). But i have data in the users table and also inside the leads table.

Table Name: users (user_id is Primary Key)

```
+----------+
|  user_id |
+----------+
|    1     |
|    2     |
|    3     |
+----------+
```

Table Name: leads (id is Primary Key and user_id is Foreign Key)

```
+-----------+----------+
|    id     | user_id  |
+-----------+----------+
|    1      |     1    |
|    2      |     2    |
|    3      |     3    |
+-----------+----------+
```

This is my code:

```
function user_leads_count() {
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT users.user_id, COUNT(leads.id) AS NumberOfLeads FROM (leads INNER JOIN users ON leads.id=users.user_id) GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(leads.id) > 0"));
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the join condition be `ON leads.user_id=users.user_id` ? Also you need to `GROUP BY user_id`, not `id`

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL

```
SELECT users.user_id, COUNT(leads.id) AS NumberOfLeads 
    FROM leads
    JOIN users USING (user_id)
GROUP by user
HAVING NumberOfLeads > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to reference the users table, if not try this should work

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS NumberOfLeads, user_id
FROM Leads
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(leads.id) > 0
```